# Unable to mock any custom class method in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-6, mockery

I have a Basic Class Helper.

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class CommonUtility {

    public static function foo() {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

And it's used in User.php

```
<?php
class User extends Authenticatable
    public function test() {
        return CommonUtility::foo();
    }
}
```

And now I wanted to write a test with mocking CommonUtility class. Can anyone know about this I'm new to laravel unit test.

Tried few solutions like

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(CommonUtility::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('foo')->andReturn('foobar');
        })->makePartial();

dd($mock->foo());
```

it gives me the mock result but i tried it from

```
$user = new \App\User();
dd($user->test());
```

It's calling the actual function instead of mock one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Aliasing](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#creating-test-doubles-aliasing) Mockery features for [Mocking Public Static Methods](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html)

As example:

```
        $mock = \Mockery::mock('alias:App\Helpers\CommonUtility');
        $mock->shouldReceive('foo')
            ->andReturn('foobar');
        
        $user = new User();
        $this->assertEquals("foobar", $user->test());
```

The test pass as expected

Comment: alias is only working when running test alone. when run the whole test suit it fails as class already exist.

Comment: alias worked the only thing i need to add is `code` /**
     * @runInSeparateProcess
     * @preserveGlobalState disabled
     */ `code` before the test

Comment: Cool! Thanks for sharing @JitenderThakur